# Connect certain file to automatically launch through a VBS/ WScript

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript, windows

On Windows Vista, I would like to open all files of a certain extension with a little VBS file (which will then pass on the parameter to a Chrome Application Shortcut app, which is actually what I want). Using a BAT or CMD file with batch commands works fine -- but shows the batch window for a second which is suboptimal -- but when using a VBS file including just a "hello world" echo, my German OS tells me something along the lines of "C:..*path-to-text-file*.. is not an admissible Win32 application". Can someone help?

Comment: Somewhat of a followup for my particular project's original goal -- getting Chrome App to launch parametrized) is this regedit file (http://blogoscoped.com/temp/chrome-launcher-reg-file.txt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBS file needs to have a .vbs extension if it doesn't already.

You can try the `ftype` and `assoc` commands.

```
assoc .yyy=YourScript
ftype YourScript=yourscript.vbs %1 %*
```

From the `help` command in `cmd`:

> Displays or modifies file types used
>   in file extension associations
>
> FTYPE [fileType[=[openCommandString]]]
>
> fileType  Specifies the file type to
>   examine or change   openCommandString
>   Specifies the open command to use when
>   launching files
>                       of this type.
>
> Type FTYPE without parameters to
>   display the current file types that
>   have open command strings defined. 
>   FTYPE is invoked with just a file
>   type, it displays the current open
>   command string for that file type.
>   Specify nothing for the open command
>   string and the FTYPE command will
>   delete the open command string for the
>   file type.  Within an open command
>   string %0 or %1 are substituted with
>   the file name being launched through
>   the assocation.  %* gets all the
>   parameters and %2 gets the 1st
>   parameter, %3 the second, etc.  %~n
>   gets all the remaining parameters
>   starting with the nth parameter, where
>   n may be between 2 and 9, inclusive. 
>   For example:
>
> ```
> ASSOC .pl=PerlScript
> FTYPE PerlScript=perl.exe %1 %*
> ```
>
> would allow you to invoke a Perl
>   script as follows:
>
> ```
> script.pl 1 2 3
> ```
>
> If you want to eliminate the need to
>   type the extensions, then do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> set PATHEXT=.pl;%PATHEXT%
> ```
>
> and the script could be invoked as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> script 1 2 3
> ```

and

> Displays or modifies file extension
>   associations
>
> ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]
>
> .ext      Specifies the file
>   extension to associate the file type
>   with   fileType  Specifies the file
>   type to associate with the file
>   extension
>
> Type ASSOC without parameters to
>   display the current file associations.
>   If ASSOC is invoked with just a file
>   extension, it displays the current
>   file association for that file
>   extension.  Specify nothing for the
>   file type and the command will delete
>   the association for the file
>   extension.